# Can I depend on a project built for an older .NET standard?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5

I am tasked with upgrading a somewhat complex C# project from .NET 4.8 to .NET 5. The Windows upgrade assistant went more or less smoothly, and with some cleanup, it looks good, Except for one dependency, which is sadly absolutely not replaceable (within the scope of the job).

So my solution to this would be: Move all the code that interfaces with this dependency to a sub-project which builds for .NET 5 as well as .NET 4.8 (at least in the csproj file), and use that as depencency. **Does this actually work?**

Visual Studio says that's ok, but I have found absolutely nothing on the topic (and while I believe it could work, it's probably just me wanting that it does).

[Regarding the problem that the result will be an absolute mess: the functionality of this dependency will be obsolete within a year, at which point the sub-project will be removed anyway, sadly the ugrade cannot just wait until then]

Comment: Yes, this was the idea behind the standard. Also note that .NET 4.8 does not support standard 2.1.

Comment: The question mentions .Net standard, but it seems like you are asking about [cross-platform targeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/cross-platform-targeting)

Comment: @GuruStron I'm talking about standard 2.0 luckily so, it should work?

Comment: @JonasH nope. Windows only

Comment: "Multi-targeting" might be better term to use. The point is, do you want to build your project for both .Net 4.8 and .Net 5, i.e. multi-targeting. Or build your project for .Net standard and use it in both .net 4.8 and .net 5 projects.

Comment: @JonasH so I can build a project in .net4.8 and include it in a project building for net5 ? Because that is my actual question, if that didnt come across

Comment: The thing is that ".Net standard" is a specific term for a set of standardized APIs, I'm guessing you mean ".Net version".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I build a project in .net4.8 and include it in a project building for net5

Maybe? The basic rule is that .Net 5 cannot use .Net 4.x libraries. There may be some exceptions to this rule, but I cannot find a reference to confirm this. And I'm fairly sure it can result in runtime failures if the library tries to use methods not available in .Net 5.

The recommended way would be to port the library to .Net standard 2.0, that way you can use it in both .Net 4.8 and .Net 5 projects without issue. This should be fairly straight forward to port unless you are using UI or other libraries not available in .net standard.

It might be possible to use [multi-targeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/cross-platform-targeting), i.e. write in your project file that the project should be compiled for both .Net 5 and .Net 4.8. You could use pragmas, (i.e. `#if NET48`) to include or exclude code sections from either framework. I have not used this feature so I cannot provide much details.